# glUniform1f error detected using OpenGL Trace View

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 2 via jni.
When going over the OpenGL Trace view of my frame rendering, I saw this error in the console:

```
error applying transformations for glUniform1f(location = 6, x = 1.000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No such property: PROGRAM_STATE/PROGRAMS/${program}/ACTIVE_UNIFORMS/6/UNIFORM_VALUE
```

It seems like I'm calling uniform for a non existing variable, so I went over all of the usages I have for this call, and also tried checking with 'glError', but I found nothing.

How can I know what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to upload to a non-existent unifom in the current program.

Did you call `glGetUniformLocation()` on *all* the symbol names in this linked version of the program?

You can't safely make assumptions that, e.g. they increment, so you really do need to call `glGetUniformLocation()` for all of them (or set binding locations directly, but that's not available until OpenGL ES 3.x).

Comment: Thanks @Isogen74. I suspect the same as well, this is why I went over all the usages, in order to see if I am trying this call on a variant too early, before setting the program. But I could not find the one to blame. I am calling glGetUniformLocation on all the symbols, of course, I am making no assumptions.  Any ideas on how to isolate the actual problem cause?

Comment: No easy option - call glGetUniformLocation on every symbol at the point the failure happens and cross-reference. More info about exactly what your shader looks like and some code (e.g. which symbol is failing) would be useful - kinda working blind here ...

Note that for things like arrays different array indices can have different binding locations, so IIRC you have to call getGetUnformLocation for every array index.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there's nothing you suggest I haven't tried. It seems not to be happening all the time. Unfortunately I cannot expose my code, so I'll just keep trying to hunt it down. Thanks for you effort.